# Can I have config files that override the system config files in PyroCMS?

Tags: pyrocms, ion-auth

Specifically, I'm trying to change the `register_redirect` in the `system/cms/modules/users/config/ion_auth.php` config file.

Is there some place to put my application specific configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially.

Config files like this are not meant to be entirely untouchable, but I understand that it feels like "hacking the core". If you're tracking your site with Git then its a non-issue, because you can pull updates without overriding the changes.

Alternatives solutions are a little tricky as the "post_user_register" event is running before it sends out activation emails and the like. That would be a good place to put your own redirect, but that would mean no users get their welcome emails so this is not a good idea.

Really you'll need to use Git for this as described above. Ion Auth is not a very flexible solution these days, compared to the awesome "Sentry" auth system being implemented for 2.3.